Some class methods failing to access some attributes of the same class, while other succeed
The overall structure of my code is to have two struttures, with their own methods, nested in a class that operates on them, like this:
class Solution {

  struct TypeText{
    //some code, attributes and methods
  };

  struct TypePattern{
    //some code, attributes and methods
    void printPattern(){} //this is the debug function that get's called in a weird way
  };

  TypeText text;
  TypePattern pattern;

  bool increaseOccurrencies(){
    //some code
    pattern.printPattern();
    //some code
  }

public:
  bool isMatch(string s, string p){
    TypeText text(s);
    TypePattern pattern(s);
    //some code
    pattern.printPattern(); //if I call this method here, it prints the correct values of pattern 
    increaseOccurrencies(); //if I call this method, that then calls pattern.printPattern, it prints a "new" pattern which is void (it has experienced only the default contructor and didn't receive the string p)
    //some code
  }


I'm autonosmly studing/practicing c++, so I expect my overall structure to be lacking, yet I'm having serius trouble understanding why this behaviour occurs...
I've tryied moving increaseOccurrencies() inside TypePattern, and that fixed the problem, but since I need to have access to TypeText too I didn't like this solution.

Seems you are practicing C++ by doing some competitive coding on Leetcode... don't do that. At least never look at solutions other people post there or you will just pick up some terrible C++ habits. One thing you are already doing wrong is passing string by value.  So my advice learn C++ somewhere else first : e.g. visit learncpp.com and then have a look at the C++ core guidelines. And only when you have bit of feel for that, go back to Leetcode

Thank you for sharing your opinion, and some valuable material; I'll definitvely read it. I usually only look at solutions after I'm happy with my own, and even I notice that some popular solution on that site are... suboptimal.
I knew that whenever I refer to class attributes (and structure attributes, I suppose?), even if I type that as a 'by value', it has direct access to the element, and therefore there's no reason to write them as 'by reference'. It somehow escaped me that this isn't true for the arguments as s and p.

By passing strings by value you also force the compiler to copy them. That is not necessary if you pass by (const) reference. e.g.  bool isMatch(const std::string& s, const std::string& p) (or you can even just use std::string_view which is const by default and in case of "const char*" strings will do the right thing without having to construct a std::string first). C++ is powerful, but it also has a lot of "complexities", so give it time :)

The problem here is that you have two objects called pattern and you are getting confused between them (or maybe you think they are the same object).
This is one pattern, it is a member of the Solution class
TypePattern pattern;

Here is the other pattern, it is a local variable in the isMatch function, it is not a member of the Solution class.
TypePattern pattern(s);

Now pattern.printPattern() in the increaseOccurrencies function operates on the pattern that is part of the Solution class, because that is the decalration that is visiable at that point. But pattern.printPattern() in the isMatch function operates on the pattern that is not part of the Solution class, because, again, that is the declaration that is visble at that point. In fact the declaration TypePattern pattern(s); hides the declaration TypePattern pattern; (technically this is called shadowing).
I would offer a solution to this problem, but I'm not completely sure what you are trying to achieve. Maybe you just need to replace
TypeText text(s);
TypePattern pattern(s);

with
text = s;
pattern = s;

so that you do not have multiple objects with similar names.
One other point (not strictly related to your question). Just because you are using TextType and TextPattern inside of Solution does not mean that you have to put the classes inside of Solution. It would be better to place them before the Solution class.
class TypeText
{
};

class TypePattern
{
};

class Solution
{
    TypeText text;
    TypePattern pattern;
};

Neted classes are rarely used in C++ because they don't really bring any benefits. It's better for classes to be independent.

I had a feeling that might have been the case; I hoped that calling the constructor to update patter would have worked, but it clearly didn't. The easiest fix should be to trasform my construttor in a new method that updates pattern, so that I don't create two items, am I right?

@JohnSmith Not that's not the solution. The solution is the one I put in the answer pattern = s; (or if your prefer pattern = TypePattern(s);). Use = to update, don't write a method to do it.

@john TypeText and TypePattern do not have a constructor nor an assignment operator that accepts a std::string. So how should text = s; and pattern = s; work ?

@wohlstad Both classes have comments which indicate that they are incomplete. I'm confident that in the actual code they have such a constructor.

@john you might be right, it makes sense. +1. Anyway the code in the question is not an ideal [mre].

I didn't write an operator= for those classes; I just wrote the default construttor ('cause the compiler complained if I didn't) and a custom construttor that was supposed to update the values. In hindsight, the constructor should be use to construct the object, not to update it...

@JohnSmith Classes have a default assignment operator too. Writing either pattern = s; or pattern = TypePattern(s); invokes that default assignment operator. To be precise what happens is that a temporary object is created using your custom constructor and that temporary object is assigned to the variable.
